# OpenGL ES Error to String

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, error-handling, native-activity

Is there a standard for getting an error string from `glGetError()` (Android and iOS) and `eglGetError()` (Android) in OpenGL ES 1.1 or 2.0?

I'm using something like this:

```
#define AssertGL(x) { x; GLenum __gle = glGetError(); Assert(__gle == GL_NO_ERROR); }
```

Would be nice to enhance this to provide text to the debugger rather than having to look up the GLenum manually of the returned value stored in `__gle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this on Android: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLU.html#gluErrorString(int) and this on
iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/gluErrorString.3.html

If those don't work for you, you can always create your own mapping from the integer error value to a corresponding string - it should be easy since there's only a handful of error values. Just look up the error values from the `gl2.h` and `gl.h` headers (they start with 0x05).

Comment: I don't think there's anything similar to GLU library for EGL afaik, you'll probably have to do that manually anyway. But again, there's only a few errors to handle.

Comment: I suppose so.  And yeah, I have to do Android manually too, because gluGetError() isn't exposed.  I did end up finding this though: https://code.google.com/p/glues/

Comment: Note that iOS link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

Just follow the specs, GL is cross-platform:

```
char const* gl_error_string(GLenum const err) noexcept
{
  switch (err)
  {
    // opengl 2 errors (8)
    case GL_NO_ERROR:
      return "GL_NO_ERROR";

    case GL_INVALID_ENUM:
      return "GL_INVALID_ENUM";

    case GL_INVALID_VALUE:
      return "GL_INVALID_VALUE";

    case GL_INVALID_OPERATION:
      return "GL_INVALID_OPERATION";

    case GL_STACK_OVERFLOW:
      return "GL_STACK_OVERFLOW";

    case GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW:
      return "GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW";

    case GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
      return "GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY";

    case GL_TABLE_TOO_LARGE:
      return "GL_TABLE_TOO_LARGE";

    // opengl 3 errors (1)
    case GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION:
      return "GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION";

    // gles 2, 3 and gl 4 error are handled by the switch above
    default:
      assert(!"unknown error");
      return nullptr;
  }
}
```